# Indentation, expressions, statements and StackOverflowException with FParsec - Errors

Tags: f#, fparsec

I test indentation with FParsec, according to [this implementation](https://github.com/stephan-tolksdorf/fparsec/wiki/Parsing-indentation-based-syntax-with-FParsec), but when I make it a little more complex by adding expressions (literals, lists, tuples and arithmetic operations), allowing expressions to top-level, and adding a variable creation statement; I first get a **StackOverflowException** error . In my opinion, this is because the expression parser is solicited in such a way as to make an infinite loop in the program. I see no other reason, however, I don't know how to fix this problem.

If I remove the `attempt pexpression` from my parser data `statement`, there is no more **StackOverflowException**, nevertheless the module `IndentationParserWithoutBacktracking` (therefore managing indentation) tells me that the code to be parsed is missing a "newline":

```
Failure: Error in Ln: 2 Col: 1
loop i 0 10
^
Expecting: let or print

The parser backtracked after:
  Error in Ln: 3 Col: 5
      let myVar = 2 + 1
      ^
  Expecting: loop or print

  The parser backtracked after:
    Error in Ln: 3 Col: 17
        let myVar = 2 + 1
                    ^
    Expecting: newline
```

All this according to the following text to be parsed:

```
loop i 0 10
    let myVar = 2 + 1
    print myVar
```

Here is my code:

```
open FParsec

// module IndentationParserWithoutBacktracking // see the link

// Utils

open IndentationParserWithoutBacktracking

let isBlank = fun c -> c = ' ' || c = '\t'
let ws  = spaces
let ws1 = skipMany1SatisfyL isBlank "whitespace"
let str s = pstring s .>> ws

let keyword str = pstring str >>? nextCharSatisfiesNot (fun c -> isLetter c || isDigit c) <?> str

// AST

type Identifier = Identifier of string

type InfixOp = 
    | Sum | Sub | Mul | Div | Pow | Mod
    | And | Or | Equal | NotEqual | Greater | Smaller | GreaterEqual | SmallerEqual

type Value =
    | Int of int
    | Float of float
    | Bool of bool
    | String of string
    | Char of char
    | Variable of Identifier

type Expr =
    | Literal of Value
    | Infix of Expr * InfixOp * Expr
    | List of Expr list
    | Tuple of Expr list

type Statement =
    | Expression of Expr
    | Let of Identifier * Statement list
    | Loop of Identifier * Expr * Expr * Statement list
    | Print of Identifier

// Literals

let numberFormat = NumberLiteralOptions.AllowMinusSign   ||| NumberLiteralOptions.AllowFraction |||
                   NumberLiteralOptions.AllowHexadecimal ||| NumberLiteralOptions.AllowOctal    |||
                   NumberLiteralOptions.AllowBinary      ||| NumberLiteralOptions.AllowPlusSign

let literal_numeric =
    numberLiteral numberFormat "number" |>> fun nl ->
        if nl.IsInteger then Literal (Int(int nl.String))
        else Literal (Float(float nl.String))

let literal_bool = 
    (choice [
        (stringReturn "true" (Literal (Bool true)))
        (stringReturn "false" (Literal (Bool false)))
    ]
    .>> ws) <?> "boolean"

let literal_string = 
    (between (pstring "\"") (pstring "\"") (manyChars (satisfy (fun c -> c <> '"')))
    |>> fun s -> Literal (String s)) <?> "string"

let literal_char = 
    (between (pstring "'") (pstring "'") (satisfy (fun c -> c <> '''))
    |>> fun c -> Literal (Char c)) <?> "character"

let identifier =
    (many1Satisfy2L isLetter (fun c -> isLetter c || isDigit c) "identifier"
    |>> fun i -> Identifier i) <?> "valid identifier"

let betweenParentheses p =
    (between (str "(") (str ")") p)

let variable = identifier |>> fun id -> Literal (Variable id)

let literal = (attempt literal_numeric  <|>
               attempt literal_bool     <|>
               attempt literal_char     <|>
               attempt literal_string   <|>
               attempt variable)        <?> "literal"

// Expressions

let pexpr, pexprimpl = createParserForwardedToRef()

let term =
    (ws >>. literal .>> ws) <|>
    (betweenParentheses (ws >>. pexpr)) <|>
    (ws >>. pexpr .>> ws)

let infixOperator (p: OperatorPrecedenceParser<_, _, _>) op prec map =
    p.AddOperator(InfixOperator(op, ws, prec, Associativity.Left, map))

let ops =
    // Arithmetic
    [ "+"; "-"; "*"; "/"; "%" ] @
    // Logical
    [ "&&"; "||"; "=="; "!="; ">"; "<"; ">="; "<=" ]

let opCorrespondance op =
    match op with
    // Arithmetic operators
    | "+"  -> Sum
    | "-"  -> Sub
    | "*"  -> Mul
    | "/"  -> Div
    | "%"  -> Mod
    // Logical operators
    | "&&" -> And
    | "||" -> Or
    | "==" -> Equal
    | "!=" -> NotEqual
    | ">"  -> Greater
    | "<"  -> Smaller
    | ">=" -> GreaterEqual
    | "<=" -> SmallerEqual

let opParser = new OperatorPrecedenceParser<_, _, _>()

for op in ops do
    infixOperator opParser op 1 (fun x y -> Infix(x, opCorrespondance op, y))

opParser.TermParser <- term

let list = between (str "[") (str "]") (sepBy pexpr (str ",")) |>> List

let tuple = between (str "(") (str ")") (sepBy pexpr (str ",")) |>> Tuple

let expression =
    opParser.ExpressionParser   <|> // I removed this line to don't have the mistake again.
    list                        <|>
    tuple                       <|>
    literal

pexprimpl := attempt expression

// Statements

let statements, statementsRef = createParserForwardedToRef()

let pexpression = expression |>> Expression

let plet =
    pipe2
        (keyword "let" >>. ws1 >>. identifier)
        (ws >>. str "=" >>. ws >>. statements)
        (fun id gtt exp -> Let(id, gtt, exp))

// From the link, but "revisited"
let ploop =
    pipe4
        (keyword "loop" >>. ws1 >>. identifier)
        (ws1 >>. literal) // If I put 'pexpr', it doesn't work too...
        (ws1 >>. literal)
        (statements)
        (fun id min max stmts -> Loop(id, min, max, stmts))

let print = keyword "print" >>. (ws1 >>. identifier |>> Print)

let statement =
    attempt plet        <|>
    attempt print       <|>
    attempt ploop       <|>
    attempt pexpression

statementsRef := indentedMany1 statement "statement"

let document = statements .>> spaces .>> eof

let test str =
    match runParserOnString document (UserState.Create()) "" str with
        | Success(result, _, _)   -> printfn "Success: %A" result
        | Failure(errorMsg, _, _) -> printfn "Failure: %s" errorMsg

System.Console.Clear()

test @"
loop i 0 10
    let myVar = 2 + 1
    print myVar
"
```

I know I ask several questions at the same time, and the site doesn't really allow it, but they're all a little linked together, so I might as well kill two birds with one stone...

I would really like to understand my mistakes, in order to design a parser for a very small ML-like language.

Thank you.

**Edit**

Here is my current code, which has been modified to respond to the first problems encountered with indentation:

```
open IndentationParserWithoutBacktracking // So from the link

let isBlank = fun c -> c = ' ' || c = '\t'
let ws  = spaces
let ws1 = skipMany1SatisfyL isBlank "whitespace"
let str s = pstring s .>> ws

let keyword str = pstring str >>? nextCharSatisfiesNot (fun c -> isLetter c || isDigit c) <?> str

// AST

type Identifier = Identifier of string

type Value =
    | Int of int
    | Float of float
    | Bool of bool
    | String of string
    | Char of char
    | Variable of Identifier

// In FP, "all" is an expression, so:

type Expr =
    // Arithmetic + lists and tuple
    | Literal of Value
    | Infix of Expr * InfixOp * Expr
    | List of Expr list
    | Tuple of Expr list
    // Statements
    | Return of Expr
    | Loop of Identifier * Expr * Expr * Expr list
    | Print of Identifier
and InfixOp = 
    | Sum | Sub | Mul | Div | Pow | Mod
    | And | Or | Equal | NotEqual | Greater | Smaller | GreaterEqual | SmallerEqual

// Literals

let numberFormat = NumberLiteralOptions.AllowMinusSign   ||| NumberLiteralOptions.AllowFraction |||
                   NumberLiteralOptions.AllowHexadecimal ||| NumberLiteralOptions.AllowOctal    |||
                   NumberLiteralOptions.AllowBinary

let literal_numeric =
    numberLiteral numberFormat "number" |>> fun nl ->
        if nl.IsInteger then Literal (Int(int nl.String))
        else Literal (Float(float nl.String))

let literal_bool = 
    (choice [
        (stringReturn "true" (Literal (Bool true)))
        (stringReturn "false" (Literal (Bool false)))
    ]
    .>> ws) <?> "boolean"

let literal_string = 
    (between (pstring "\"") (pstring "\"") (manyChars (satisfy (fun c -> c <> '"')))
    |>> fun s -> Literal (String s)) <?> "string"

let literal_char = 
    (between (pstring "'") (pstring "'") (satisfy (fun c -> c <> '''))
    |>> fun c -> Literal (Char c)) <?> "character"

let identifier =
    (many1Satisfy2L isLetter (fun c -> isLetter c || isDigit c) "identifier"
    |>> fun i -> Identifier i) <?> "identifier"

let betweenParentheses p =
    (between (str "(") (str ")") p) <?> ""

let variable = identifier |>> fun id -> Literal (Variable id)

let literal = (attempt literal_numeric  <|>
               attempt literal_bool     <|>
               attempt literal_char     <|>
               attempt literal_string   <|>
               attempt variable)        <?> "literal"

// Expressions and statements

let pexprs, pexprimpl = createParserForwardedToRef()

// `ploop` is located here to force `pexprs` to be of the type `Expr list`, `ploop` requesting an expression list.
let ploop =
    pipe4
        (keyword "loop" >>. ws1 >>. identifier)
        (ws1 >>. literal)
        (ws1 >>. literal)
        (pexprs)
        (fun id min max stmts -> Loop(id, min, max, stmts))

// `singlepexpr` allows to use only one expression.
let singlepexpr =
    pexprs |>> fun ex -> ex.Head

let term =
    (ws >>. singlepexpr .>> ws) <|>
    (betweenParentheses (ws >>. singlepexpr)) <|>
    (ws >>. literal .>> ws) <|>
    (betweenParentheses (ws >>. literal))

let infixOperator (p: OperatorPrecedenceParser<_, _, _>) op prec map =
    p.AddOperator(InfixOperator(op, ws, prec, Associativity.Left, map))

let ops =
    // Arithmetic
    [ "+"; "-"; "*"; "/"; "%" ] @
    // Logical
    [ "&&"; "||"; "=="; "!="; ">"; "<"; ">="; "<=" ]

let opCorrespondance op =
    match op with
    // Arithmetic operators
    | "+"  -> Sum
    | "-"  -> Sub
    | "*"  -> Mul
    | "/"  -> Div
    | "%"  -> Mod
    // Logical operators
    | "&&" -> And
    | "||" -> Or
    | "==" -> Equal
    | "!=" -> NotEqual
    | ">"  -> Greater
    | "<"  -> Smaller
    | ">=" -> GreaterEqual
    | "<=" -> SmallerEqual

let opParser = new OperatorPrecedenceParser<Expr, unit, UserState>()

for op in ops do
    infixOperator opParser op 1 (fun x y -> Infix(x, opCorrespondance op, y))

opParser.TermParser <- term

let list = (between (str "[") (str "]") (sepBy singlepexpr (str ",")) |>> List) <?> "list"

let tuple = (between (str "(") (str ")") (sepBy singlepexpr (str ",")) |>> Tuple) <?> "tuple"

// Statements

// A commented `let` expression, commented for tests with the `return` instruction.

//let plet =
//    pipe3
//        (keyword "let" >>. ws1 >>. identifier)
//        (ws >>. gtt ":")
//        (ws >>. str "=" >>. ws >>. pexprs)
//        (fun id gtt exp -> Let(id, gtt, exp))

let preturn = 
    keyword "return" >>. ws >>. singlepexpr
    |>> fun ex -> Return ex

let print = keyword "print" >>. (ws1 >>. identifier |>> Print)

let instruction =
    print <|>
    ploop <|>
    preturn <|>

    opParser.ExpressionParser <|> // So we add the arithmetic, like x + y or 21 * 32 - 12 for example
    list <|>
    tuple <|>
    literal

pexprimpl := indentedMany1 instruction "instruction"

let document = pexprs .>> spaces .>> eof

let test str =
    match runParserOnString document (UserState.Create()) "" str with
        | Success(result, _, _)   -> printfn "%A" result
        | Failure(errorMsg, _, _) -> printfn "%s" errorMsg

System.Console.Clear()

// The test code that give an error of "newline" expecting
let code = test @"
return 2 + 1
"
```

And here some screenshots about error:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `indentedMany1` tells you it's expecting a newline in your example code is because that's what it's looking for: an indented *block*. Not an expression on one line. So your `let myVar = 2 + 1` line is confusing it. If you wrote it as:

```
let myVar =
    2 + 1
```

then I bet it would work.

What you need, I believe, is to change your `let` parser to allow one of two things: *either* an expression on a single line, *or* a block of statements (your `statements` parser). I.e., something like:

```
let pLetValue = expression <|> statements
let plet =
    pipe2
        (keyword "let" >>. ws1 >>. identifier)
        (ws >>. str "=" >>. ws >>. pLetValue)
        (fun id gtt exp -> Let(id, gtt, exp))
```

Note that I haven't tested this, as I don't have much time today. It's possible that instead of `expression` above, you'd want `attempt expression` (or `pexpr`, which is the same thing). Experiment a little and see what happens; and if you're completely lost as you try to figure out how FParsec is handling a given expression, remember the advice given in http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/users-guide/debugging-a-parser.html.

Comment: I'm also not happy in general with seeing `attempt p1 <|> attempt p2 <|> attempt p3` chains. IMHO, the final parser in a chain should not use `attempt`, e.g. my example should be written as `attempt p1 <|> attempt p2 <|> p3`. If all parsers in the chain use `attempt`, then the chain can (and often will) *succeed* while consuming zero bytes even though p1, p2 and p3 all failed. IMHO, if p1, p2 and p3 all fail, then the parser chain should *fail*, not succeed with zero bytes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately what you are proposing did not work. I tried other variants, but to no avail. The `pLetValue` causes a compilation problem: this expression was supposed to have the type *Statement list* but have the type *Statement*; for all parsers using it. If I try to box it: `[pLetValue]` in the expression, there is also an error: This expression was supposed to have the type *Parser<'a,' b>* but here has the type *'c list*. And it's only for the expression that uses it locally here.
In the text to be analysed, he constantly asks for a new line.
Thank you to you

Comment: Ah; I hadn't looked closely at your model. Since you've defined a `Let` to take a *list* of statements, then instead of `expression` inside `pLetValue`, you'll need something like `expression |>> (fun expr -> [expr])`. Putting the parser in a list isn't correct; you need to put the parser's result in a list. As usual with F# type errors, once you figure out the type error your program is closer to working correctly.

Comment: This now works for indentation, all instructions work, however, even following your instructions, the parser always asks me for a new line after each instruction waiting for an arithmetic expression.
This error occurs every time `pexpr` or `singlepexpr` is called.
I really don't understand where the error can come from, having followed the documentation, examples, the debugger and your advice (which still helped me).
I edited the initial post with my current code, as well as some screenshots about the error...
Once again, I thank you for your help.